# Inno Setup, CreateInputDirPage, install dir

Tags: inno-setup

I have a setup that use custom page (`CreateInputDirPage` with two directory, application and data) to ask the user for install directory.

How I can set in Inno Setup the install dir with `CreateInputDirPage` directory, and so Inno Setup writes this directory in registry instead of default directory?